# rcharts: nPlot Formating x-axis with dates

Tags: r, rcharts

I have a data.frame with dates and integers:

```
  df <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012/01/01"), to=as.Date("2012/02/28"), by="1 day"), y=1:59)
```

I want to plot the data.frame with rCharts nPlot:

```
  n <- nPlot(y ~ date, group = "team", data = df, type = "lineChart")
  n$xAxis(
    tickFormat =   "#!
      function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%M-%d')(new Date(d));}
    !#",
    rotateLabels = -90
  )
  n
```

But the x-axis isn't formatted correctly.

[image: nPlot with wrong x-axis]

So how do I format the dates correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R as.numeric(someDate) is days since origin. Here we need milliseconds from origin. 
So it should be

```
  df <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012/01/01", origin="1970-01-01"), to=as.Date("2012/02/28", origin="1970-01-01"), by="1 day"), y=1:59)

  n <- nPlot(y ~ date, group = "team", data = df, type = "lineChart")
  n$xAxis(
    tickFormat =   "#!
      function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24));}
    !#",
    rotateLabels = -90
  )
  n
```

Answer (score 0):

%M is minute, what you want is `%m` which will get you months:

```
 n <- nPlot(y ~ date, group = "team", data = df, type = "lineChart")
  n$xAxis(
    tickFormat =   "#!
      function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d));}
    !#",
    rotateLabels = -90
  )
  n
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. But that doesn't solve the problem. The year is still wrong! I get still 1970-01-01 for all dates.

Comment: try changing the case to `%y`?

Comment: No, then I get 70-01-01. So there must be something wrong with either the type of df$date or with the function in tichFormat...

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459687/understanding-nvd3-x-axis-date-format d is in milliseconds, so it should be  `function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d*1000));}` but the output is still not okay.