# how do I display hours and days on the y-axis for nvd3 / d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

In my code of nvd3, I have a range of times which needs to be passed. X-axis contains dates and y-axis contains time and I want it formatted like the following on y-axis:

1. 2hrs 30 mins
2. 1 day 2 hours 30 mins
3. 3 days 4 hours 30 mins

How can I have these dynamically set on y-axis?

Comment: Could you add your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), someone could have a proper look on the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding nvd3 x-axis date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459687/understanding-nvd3-x-axis-date-format)