# How to convert time range to display in hours not date? (nvd3 chart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

http://plnkr.co/edit/19D5cnrVYdUrMlblQARy?p=preview

[image]

Above is my chart, the values I've passed it are for 1 day, 30 minute intervals:

```
var data =[{
  "key" : "Price",
  "color" : "#4C73FF",
  "values" : [ [ 1443621600000 , 71.89],
               [ 1443619800000 , 75.51],
               [ 1443618000000 , 68.49],
               [ 1443616200000 , 62.72],
               [ 1443612600000 , 70.39],
               [ 1443610800000 , 59.77]]
}];
```

Which correspond to the following ([Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)):

```
9/30/2015, 9:00:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
9/30/2015, 8:30:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
9/30/2015, 8:00:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
9/30/2015, 7:30:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
9/30/2015, 6:30:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
9/30/2015, 6:00:00 AM GMT-5:00 DST
```

How do I change the format of the date on the chart from showing `9/30/2015` to show instead `9:00`?

I couldn't find anything in their docs talking about time or timespans http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#line

Full code from Directive:

```
var data =[{
  "key" : "Price",
  "color" : "#4C73FF",
  "values" : [ [ 1443621600000 , 71.89],
               [ 1443619800000 , 75.51],
               [ 1443618000000 , 68.49],
               [ 1443616200000 , 62.72],
               [ 1443612600000 , 70.39],
               [ 1443610800000 , 59.77]]
}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
    .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
    .x(function(d,i) { return i })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(false)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
      return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
    });

  chart.y1Axis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

  chart.y2Axis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });

  chart.bars.forceY([0]);

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

Comment: what formats are your dates in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this question [Understanding nvd3 x-axis date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459687/understanding-nvd3-x-axis-date-format)

Which helped me find this: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

I'm able to correct change time now:

From my `timerangeConvertFactory`
 service I just made

```
function convertTime(when) {
    switch(when) {
        case 'lh':
        case 'ld':
            return '%I:%M';
            break;
        case 'lw':
        case '1mo':
        case '3mo':
            return '%x';
            break;
        case '1yr':
        case '2yr':
        case 'max':
            return '%m:%y';
            break;
    }
}
```

And now back in my Directive:

```
// Get timespan:
var timeRange = TimeSpanFactory.getTimeSpan();
console.log('timeRange =',timeRange.when);

// Convert timespan to nvd3 format:
var nvd3timeRange = TimespanConvertFactory.convertTime(timeRange.when);
console.log('nvd3timeRange =',nvd3timeRange);

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
        .margin({top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 40})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = res[0].values[d] && res[0].values[d][0] || 0;
        return d3.time.format(nvd3timeRange)(new Date(dx))
        // return d3.time.format('%I:%M')(new Date(dx))
        // return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
    });
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
d3.time.format('%H')
```

instead of

```
d3.time.format('%x')
```

because

> %x - date, as "%m/%d/%Y"

Here you can find all the sources of D3 time formats

source : [github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)